# Importing from text, delimiter "blank space" also used for separating first name from last name

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I got some data in a txt file containing the value someone should receive, the name of the person and the reason for the payment. These 3 informations are separated by a blank space. When I try to import it to excel I face a peculiar problem, selecting "blank space" as a delimiter between columns results in a mess, because people's name vary from 2 words to 4 words. Is there an easy way to make excel keep the name of a person in the same column, while the other information in other columns?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excel can't recognize names as you recognize them, so the simple answer is NO, Excel can't do that. However, if you post some sample data, we might help you finding a solution to split that data into columns as desired.

Comment: Help us to help you, **post a sample of your data**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are your value and reason for payment only one string phrases? As is "$94.34, Jane Jones Drew, Overtime"

If so, Cut/Paste the Reason in front of name, delimit by space, and Concatenate the rest of the cells. Something like `=CONCATENATE(D1," ",E1," ",F1)` etc.

The `" "` will put the space back in so the name looks right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake committed by whoever made that txt file you were given.  You should make them fix it.

If you can't, I can only hope that the data in the "reason" field has no spaces or at least a predictable number of them.  Without that someones going to have to fix this by hand.

There are crazier workarounds but they're brittle.  Meaning you'd have to keep checking that they worked.